# Python Pytube download 320kbps mp3

Tags: python-3.x, youtube, mp3, pytube

Is it possible to download a youtube stream with pytube that has 320 kpbs bitrate? I only get 124 kpbs back when using the `streams.filter(progressive=True).last()`, `yt_link.streams.filter(progressive=True).first()` or `yt_link.streams.get_highest_resolution()` and converting it to an mp3 file with:

```
from moviepy.editor import *            
video = VideoFileClip(yt_output_file)
audio = video.audio
audio.write_audiofile(download_folder + "\\" + yt_link.title + ".mp3")
audio.close()
video.close()
```

I also tried by itag (yt_link.streams.get_by_itag()), which sometimes gave a 160kpbs mp3 file and when not available a 128kpbs file after converting it to mp3.

Thanks

Stream prints:
yt_link.streams.filter(progressive=True).last():
<Stream: itag="17" mime_type="video/3gpp" res="144p" fps="8fps" vcodec="mp4v.20.3" acodec="mp4a.40.2" progressive="True" type="video">

yt_link.streams.filter(progressive=True).first()
<Stream: itag="22" mime_type="video/mp4" res="720p" fps="30fps" vcodec="avc1.64001F" acodec="mp4a.40.2" progressive="True" type="video">

yt_link.streams.get_highest_resolution()
<Stream: itag="22" mime_type="video/mp4" res="720p" fps="30fps" vcodec="avc1.64001F" acodec="mp4a.40.2" progressive="True" type="video">

MP3 files:
[image]

Download an mp4 youtube file and convert it from mp4 to mp3 with 320 kpbs.

Comment: The reason why you are not able to get a stream with a bitrate of 320 kbps is that `streams.filter(progressive=True)` only returns streams that are both video and audio combined, which means that the maximum bitrate of the audio is limited to 128 kbps.
And also keep in mind that not all YouTube videos have an audio stream with a bitrate of 320 kbps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Okay I didn't know that progressive filter only returns video and audio streams combined. What I don't understand is that using yt_link.streams.get_highest_resolution() or yt_link.streams.filter(only_audio=True, abr='320kbps').first() only returns 128/160 kpbs for most files, while you can download it with 320 kpbs on https://yt1s.de/youtube-to-mp3?l=en. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example helps you.
We use the `only_audio=True` filter to select only the audio streams and order those audio streams by their audio bitrate (abr) in descending order, and then select the first audio stream in the resulting list.
And you can also find online different examples of how to download YouTube videos using different python libraries.

```
    import pytube
    from moviepy.editor import *
    
    yt_link = pytube.YouTube('youtube link')
    audio_stream = yt_link.streams.filter(only_audio=True).order_by('abr').desc()
    audio_file = audio_stream.download(output_path=download_folder)
    
    video = VideoFileClip(audio_file)
    audio = video.audio
    audio.write_audiofile(download_folder + "\\" + yt_link.title + ".mp3")
    audio.close()
    video.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This didn't work for me so far because all the links I tried don't have a 320kbps stream... I'm trying to understand why I can't pull it from youtube with 320kbps while youtube converts can do it for videos with only 128 kpbs streams. FYI: I'm also using a try and except block but didn't mention it here since it wouldn't make any difference. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Online video converters that allow you to download a video's audio track at a higher bitrate than the original video may use different audio encoding settings and algorithms than Pytube or YouTube's own audio conversion that's why you can download every video at 320kps. Also, I modified the response to download the  the audio stream with the highest available bitrate for the given video. @Gishub